# How can I globally ignore lint for imports that are only used in JSDoc param types?

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint, jsdoc, commonjs

I introduced eslint into my backend. Now I get lint errors for code like the following example.

```js
const ImAClass = require("../models/ImAClass.model.js");
 
/**
* Gets the class
* @param {ImAClass} class
* @returns {ImAClass} Returns the class
*/
function getClass(class) { 
    return class;
}
```

This will lead to the following error:

`error  'ImAClass' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars`

How can I get rid of this error, without spamming `// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars`?

Comment: you can catch it on https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-vars

Comment: Thanks for the hint - in the last sentence I made a mistake by asking how I can fix this without using `// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef` - I meant that I don't want to use `// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars` but instead have a global rule or something like this.

Comment: go and use global configuration from here and make changes according to you https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/getting-started